# Data Import Wizard : - Lookup Relations Issue

Tags: data-import-wizard, data-import

I am not sure but I am wondering if there was a recent change in the Data Import Wizard tool as now it requires the `Id` of all the lookup relations from a particular object whilst before was working with only specifying the `name` of the record and was able fetch the required `id` based on the name you input.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail please @Marc Zaharescu - is this a custom object or standard and which other objects does it have the lookup relationships to?

Comment: I have tried to import a set of Accounts which have lookup relations to different Custom Objects. Before I was able to only specify the name of the records in the lookup and it would match the id automatically, but now I need to specify the id of the record.

Comment: You could try dataloader.io which can do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we've also encountered this problem, but unfortunately it is due to a change in the Data Import Wizard which now requires salesforce IDs for all look up fields. The error message generated is:'Your import failed: Import for object Account did not succeed. Error received - null'
I've had several lengthy conversations with salesforce help with this (and apparently they've had a lot of complaints about it), as it is completely impractical for us to enter salesforce IDs instead of recognisable names/titles, and unfortunately no way to solve without entering IDs until Salesforce change back to the old system. We are trying to get Salesforce to change, I've posted this as an 'Idea', so if you are having problems with this, please vote on my idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003OryQAE

Answer (score 0):

Solution-

1. Use data loader to update record, via data loader you will see the account look up fields. If you use data import wizard you will not see the look up fields.
2. Use account name to account Id so will update as account name